# Get offset/height of a child component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have the following structure, Child component have set of GrandChild components - recursively generated - so the page can have n number of grandchild components - I need to know when the page scrolls if the Grandchild element is scrolled through its height on Parent component to add some css styling on other component `Child2`. Not sure how to do this? should that be height calculation? please help.

```
 Parent component:

  class Parent extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.blocks = [];
      }

      componentDidMount() {

     }

    render() {

      return (
       <Child1 />
       <Child2 />
       );
    }

}
```

Child1:

```
class Child1 extends Component {

      componentDidMount() {

      }

       render() {   
         return (
           <div>
            <GrandChild />
          </div>
         );
       }  
     }
```

GrandChild:

```
class GrandChild extends Component {

       render() {   
         return (
           <div>
            <p class="paragraph" />
          </div>
         );
       }  
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually,if root div and the element all have scroll property, they maintain their own scrollbar.You can use the below method to add listener to scroll event.

```
componentDidMount(){
    window.addEventListener('scroll',()=> {
        var header = this.refs.header
        var scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop ||            document.documentElement.scrollTop
        if(scrollTop>300){
            console.log(scrollTop)
        }
        var listener = document.getElementById("Child1")
        listener.addEventListener('scroll',() => {
            console.log('scroll')
        })
    })
}
```